# Django (Ubuntu): What is the best way to use npm for front-end dependency management

Tags: django, npm

How I used to create my Django projects

- `mkvirtualenv env1` - creates virtual environment env1
- `pip install -r requirements.txt` - install some python modules
- `pip install nodeenv` - for isolated node environments
- `nodeenv -p` - This commands installs nodejs and adds new shell functions to our virtualenvwrapper shell functions. Directory node_modules was put inside env1 directory
- `npm install -g bower` - Bower directory was put in node_modules inside env1.
- `pip install django-bower` - I set `BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/PROJECT_ROOT/components/'`
- I set `BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS` and run `./manage.py bower install`. Packages listed in `BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS` were installed into `'/PROJECT_ROOT/components/bower_components'`
- at the end I used `django-compressor`

However Bower is now apparently no longer a thing, so i need a new setup. For now I decided, that I'm gonna use only npm for front-end dependency management. So my question is, if the following setup is good enough. NOTE - I am a complete rookie regarding npm and javascript environments

- Create nodeenv environment inside virtualenv env1. Then in django project root I run `npm init` which creates `package.json`, and then from the same directory I run `npm install foundation-sites --save` for example. This creates node_modules in project root. Then I could use `django-compressor` with precompilers that work on node_modules directory (the one inside project root). So with this setup one node_modules directory is in env1, and the only package inside is npm (if I understand correctly, npm is installed glodally but still within virtual environment). Foundation package and its dependencies are in directory node_modules inside project root (installed locally within virtual environment).

Is nodeenv even necessary for this purpose or is it better if npm is installed  globally (outside of virtual environments) and then for each project we run `npm init` and install all packages locally. I don't know if this even works.